# Find amount of index's before a threshold value is met

Tags: r

I have a problem in R, where I have a vector, and I want to count at which index, a threshold value is first met.

so I have like

```
     [0,3,2,7,13,2,12,13]
```

and I want to know at which index, the value exceeds `12`, which would be entry nr. `5`.

Thanks!

Comment: use `which.max` i.e. `which.max(v1>12)` where `v1 <- c(0,3,2,7,13,2,12,13)`

Comment: Or just `which(v1>12)[1L]` if your vector is big

Comment: @DavidArenburg The `which` method is faster on testing with a 1e7 vector.

Comment: @akrun yes I know :) Didn't think you are going to actually test it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You could post the comments as a solution as I didn't find a duplicate using some key words

Comment: Thanks! which.max worked perfectly.

Comment: @akrun it's fine, I've just commented on your comment. The are many ways of achieving this. You can post it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
which.max(v1>12)
```

Or as @DavidArenburg commented, a faster option would be

```
which(v1>12)[1L]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0,3,2,7,13,2,12,13)
```